# Old '90s-ish cartoon, where a band gets powers from a gem/rock

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don't remember alot from this show because I watched it at such a young age.

Basically a rock (maybe punk?) band that isnt doing too well somehow gets powers from a gem. Their powers resemble their instruments. I believe a female character teaches them how to use those powers?

Either way, I've been trying to remember the name of it for the past few years and I haven't been able to find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: If you could remember anything else about this show it would be very helpful. When did you see it approximately, was it a few decades ago or way back in the early days of rock. Was the style in western animation or manga. Do you remember any names of the characters?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 13):

It might be [Stone protectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Protectors) a cartoon from 1996 based on a toyline with the same name. It is about a bad band that gets access to magic gems that a magic princess called Opal tries to hide. After they save her from the villain of the show she teaches them how to use them as superheroes.

[image]

From Wikipedia:

> After being thrown out the back door of a New York City club, an awful rock band known as the Rock Detectors found the five magical stones which gave them troll-like appearances and special skills (not the least of which is playing good music). This put them at odds with the music-hating Zok and his henchman Zink, collectively known as The Prodtectors.
>
> - Cornelius, the group's leader, holds the green stone and became a samurai with an assortment of appropriate weaponry (katana, shuriken, and a pair of nunchaku made of microphones). He is the band's lead singer, but also plays the guitar.
> - Chester holds the red stone, became an expert at wrestling and received great strength. He plays the bass guitar and saxophone.
> - Clifford holds the blue stone and became a "rock climber." He is the band's drummer.
> - Angus holds the yellow stone and became a "soldier" and an expert at turning mundane objects into weapons. He plays the keyboard. Angus ostensibly built up the Protectors' bizarre attack vehicles from things like barbecues and lawnmowers.
> - Maxwell holds the orange stone and became an "accelerator" with in-line skates. He plays the guitar.