# Old anime series where a clumsy kid was kinda beamed up into space and met with a princess

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic, space

It looked like maybe '90s-2000s. I remember there was a clumsy kid who was supposed to be a chosen one or something and was kinda beamed up into space and met with a princess.

Don't remember what the princess looked like (I think I remember some pink ??), but the kid had glasses, brown hair, I'm pretty sure some bandages and normal looking clothes. At first he declined but I don't remember much past the 1st/2nd episode.

It was the first one I watched and I can't find it.

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this, and did you see it on TV or online? If on TV, then in which country and language?

Comment: Also, it'd be appreciated if you'd post a comment in this [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245267/old-90s-ish-cartoon-where-a-band-gets-powers-from-a-gem-rock) of yours to clarify whether the answer submitted there is correct or incorrect.

Comment: Or better yet, check the check mark on the answer.